# In Wildfly, is there a difference between including a JAR file in my WAR as opposed to linking to it via jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Tags: deployment, java-8, wildfly, classloader, war

I'm using Wildfly 11 with Java 8.  If I deploy two WAR files with identical libraries

```
/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
```

Is there any advantage to including these libraries in the /WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml like so

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
        <deployment>
                <dependencies>
            ...
                        <module name="org.javassist" />
```

as opposed to including the JAR in my WAR files?  That is, do I cut down on memory due to class loading or any similar advantage?

Comment: this is probably related to your previous question, so I'll just repeat myself, this IS an XY problem, you are asking for a solution for a problem that we are absolutely un-aware of. there are plenty of users that can help you here **IFF** you would let them know clearly what is going on...

Comment: Yes, you can always create your own module and define its dependency through jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to load jar files.

Comment: @Abhijit, Yes but are there any performance advantages to doing that, as in what are the JVM memory implications and application speed fallout?

Answer (score 1):

More than any advantage in memory or performance (that JBoss modules claims it can do), i think JBoss modules are more for take advantage of reuse of modules, or separate versions of the same module.

If you check the structure of the JBoss modules in file system, it remembers maven repository style, in this way you can review more easily the modules and versions available, or you can check the dependencies with the same tools of JBoss AS, as CLI or the Web console.

If you have an application and you can't scale a version of a specific framework/library you can stay with it, and you can have other applications with other versions of the same library. I know you can reach the same when you embed your jars into your application, but you have to do the same thing in all of your apps, with JBoss modules you just have to declare your dependencies and your application will be more lightweight.

In JBoss modules every jar you configure are a module, and every module has its own class loader(modular class loader), and every class loader knows exactly what classes it has to load (and its dependencies if apply), against a flat class loader (hierarchical), that loads all classes. This architecture makes JBoss modules faster (basically because is a new way to do the same thing of its ancestor, the JDK class loader).

[In this link](https://jboss-modules.github.io/jboss-modules/manual/), you can check a more specific guide of JBoss modules that explains more concepts and surely has a better explanation.

[In this link](http://planet.jboss.org/post/modularized_java_with_jboss_modules), you can find a short review and a pair of examples.

Hope this helps.