# Jboss module vs JAR in deployment descriptor

Tags: maven, module, jar, jboss, dependencies

What will take precedence, a module added as maven dependency and added in EAR's deployment descriptor or a Jboss module, for ex. jaxb jar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Wildfly, is there a difference between including a JAR file in my WAR as opposed to linking to it via jboss-deployment-structure.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648513/in-wildfly-is-there-a-difference-between-including-a-jar-file-in-my-war-as-oppo)

Comment: Thanks for the links, this was very helpful, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, why do you want to add maven dependency to deployment descriptor? It is weird.

If your code want to use jaxb classes then class loader will find them in EAR (maven dependency).

If your code want to use a class from some third module (ex. jax-ws) and that module want to call jaxb then class loader will find jaxb in JBoss module. If versions are different errors can appears. It can be cause of redeploy memory leak.

I recommend to make maven scope provided. And use module from JBoss.